# C# variable in an xpath selector

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

Can I pass a C# string variable into an xpath selector?  This is for a selenium unit test.  I want to do something like this:

```
string myText = "foo";    
Assert.IsTrue(Browser.IsElementPresent("//option[contains(text(), $myText)]"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string myText = "foo";    
Assert.IsTrue(Browser.IsElementPresent(String.Format("//option[contains(text(), {0})]", myText)));
```

Comment: Warning: This approach is vulnerable to xpath injection attacks if the variable represents user input.  Probably not relevant for the OP's situation, but just so others don't use this approach blindly.

Answer (score 6):

Using a string.Format should work:

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(Browser.IsElementPresent(string.Format("//option[contains(text(), {0}]",myText)));
```

Comment: There was an additional error that I fixed.  Darn fast-typing.

Comment: still +1 because of being the fastest one in answering the question;)

Answer (score 0):

I see this has already been answered but you could also just do:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Browser.IsElementPresent(String.Format("//option[contains(text(), " + myText + ")]")));
```

This works because C# will just append each string to the end of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!  I was doing a Find in a table, and the above solutions did not work for me, possibly because my string contained hyphens, a decimal point, and numerals like so: "TV-8888-ZIP-54-EN-CTR.05021031"

I assigned the string to the C# variable ID.  The answers above failed, I suspect, due to the decimal point and numerals.  Using Nashibukasan's answer, I had to explicitly add single quotes.  The working Find statement--that gets the value in the third column of the table from the same row that contains the ID string in the first column--ended up looking like this:

```
value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//td[contains(text()," + "'" + ID + "'" + ")]/following-sibling::td[2]"))).Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string myxpath = "grdCntr_chkgrd_" + ctr;

IWebElement e = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[@id='{0}']", myxpath)));
```